# How to fix warning on iPad segue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uistoryboardsegue

I was wondering if someone could explain this to me. I'm building a universal app using storyboards. The iPhone version has a navigation controller with a master list view and then a sub-list view (both are tableview controllers.

The iPad app uses a split view controller to achieve the same thing as the iphone (a master list, with a detail list). All is good, however when using the "replace" segue to transition to a new detail view on the split view controller I have to embed the new detail views within their own navigation controller, whereas I don't need to do this on the iphone (it's already within a navigation controller. (Hopefully this makes some sense)

My code (which works) ends up looking like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NotesListViewController *listNotesView;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        listNotesView = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
    } else {
        listNotesView = [segue destinationViewController];
    }

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NotesByDate"]) {
        [listNotesView setGroupType:@"date"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NotesByTopic"]) {
        [listNotesView setGroupType:@"topics"];
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"NotesBySpeaker"]) {
        [listNotesView setGroupType:@"speaker"];
    }
```

So... The issue is that the first condition of the IF statement is generating a warning (incompatible pointer type assigning to NoteListViewController from UIViewController). However, it isn't a UIViewController, it's a UITableViewController. On the iPhone version it WOULD be a UIView, but I'm specifically checking for iPad here.

Like I said, it works, so maybe this isn't really an issue, but I'm a bit annoyed by the warning constantly appearing and being unsure of how/if I can fix it.

I'll try to post images of the storyboards in a bit, hopefully that helps explain this some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is typecast the UIViewController you retrieve with `[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]` to a `NotesListViewController`.

So, you would have `listNotesView = (NotesListViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];`

As an aside, the reason your code works but generates a warning is because regardless of what type you call an object, the actual type that is pointed to in memory is what matters(You can declare something as an `NSString` and allocate the memory with `[NSDictionary alloc]`, but that would just lead to confusion). `-topViewController` returns a `UIViewController` object because somewhere along the line, any class it returns will inherit from `UIViewController`, like your `NotesListViewController` does, but it doesn't have enough information to be any more specific than that, so you have to give the compiler the extra information by typecasting the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the solution! That makes perfect sense.